# Does an observable keep emitting values after observer has unsubscribed?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Let's consider the following example code:

```
gude() {
  const digestor$ = new Observable(subscriber => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 4711; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const hash = createHashWithNLeadingZeroes(i);
        subscriber.next(hash);
      }, i);
    }
  });

  const subscription = digestor$.subscribe(
    _ => {
      if (subscription) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Within the function *gude()* a new observable is created which emits hash values that have the first *n* leading values set to zero. An observer subscribes to that observable and immediately unsubscribes. Let's assume that the function *createHashWithNLeadingZeroes()* takes quite a bit of time to generate a response.

IMHO the following is happening here:

(1) A new Observable is created and the function describing the behavior of the Observable is internally stored in the property *_subscribe* (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts: 37-41).

(2) When *subscribe()* is called, first the Observer is wrapped in a *Subscriber* object, and second that *Subscriber* is applied to the *_subscribe* function which holds the Observable's logic. *_subscribe()* returns quickly as only 4711 timeout's are set and a Subscription object is returned (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts: 206-250).

The Subscriber basically intercepts calls to *next()*, *error()*, and *complete()* and only forwards to the actual observer when internally the property *isStopped* is not set (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscriber.ts: 90-128).

(3) As soon as the variable *subscription* is set, *unsubscribe()* is called. Among others, this will lead to setting *isStopped* to true so that the Subscriber will not forward the hashes to the observer anymore (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscriber.ts: 130-136).

According to that logic the Observable however would still continue doing its job until all 4711 hashes are computed for no purpose as the observer's methods are turned to noops. Ultimately, such a behavior can affect the application's performance depending on the amount of subscriptions and workload of the Observable's. I find it somewhat hard to believe that the described is correct. Which part am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a ["hot" Observable](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) so it's emitting even when there are no subscribers.

When creating Observables with `new Observable()` you can optionally return so called teardown (or dispose) function that should cleanup any resources if needed.

So in your case you'll want to stop the timer.

```
new Observable(subscriber => {
  ...
  const handler = setTimeout(() => {...});

  return () => clearTimeout(handler);
});
```

Or if you have multiple timers you'd call `clearTimeout` on all of them.

Answer (score 1):

> Which part am I missing here?

I think the part you're missing is that it's the responsibility of the observable to respect the contract: if it's being asked to stop emitting, it should stop emitting. So your observable should do the following:

```
const digestor$ = new Observable(subscriber => {
  let keepGoing = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < 4711 && keepGoing; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (keepGoing) {
        const hash = createHashWithNLeadingZeroes(i);
        subscriber.next(hash);
      }
    }, i);

    return () => keepGoing = false; // this function is called when the subscriber unsubscribes
  }
});
```

It's usually a better idea to rely on existing factory functions and operators to achieve the desired behavior. You could do the equivalent of the above observable by using `range()`, `timer()` and `map()`, for example.